# Adding legends to multiple maps

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

I have many ggplots with 2 legends each. I want to create two standardized legends that I can add on to my maps. I have tried the get_legend function to create each of these legends and added them to my maps. When I do this, the legends are as large as the maps. Is there a way to adjust the size and location of the legends?

```
legend<- get_legend(mvc08)
legend2<- get_legend(legendhr)
c1<- abplot08 + abplot12+ abplot14+ abplot15+ legend + legend2
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: If you want to add the same legend to each map, consider defining it completely in the ggplot call.  If you define the colors, range, breaks, etc. it will be identical across all plots.  Just paste the same scale definition and add an appropriate position in the theme.